# ATtiny: no support for multiplication?

Tags: avr, attiny

Is it true that the ATtiny AVRs have no hardware support for multiplication? It seems to work fine as I do multiplication in my code. I've also included math.h and have a couple of sin() and cos() calculations. Am I running into some huge 800-cycle penalty for these calculations, does anyone know?

Comment: use lookup tables for trig, and linear interpolation if you want better resolution (with tolerable error)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ATtiny does not have a hardware multiplier, but software multiplication is not quite as expensive as you imply. See the [AVR200 application note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0936.pdf) and [associated code](http://www.atmel.com/Images/AVR200.zip) for some optimized multiplication and division routines.

Sine and cosine calculations can be accelerated using lookup tables, effectively trading memory space for processor cycles. However, as @DaveTweed correctly pointed out, algorithmically approximating sine and cosine in software will push the cycle count up nearer the range you fear.

Comment: Polynomial approximation for `sin()` and `cos()` typically involve several (3-5) multiplications, plus multiprecision adds/subtracts, range folding, etc., so 800 clocks per function call is not unrealistic.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Thank you, good point. Edited to clarify.